# Any solution to screen lock-up relating to nvidia driver issue and touchpad use?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, touchpad

First time question--
My Asus G750JW laptop with a 765m gpu seems to work fine.  Running Ubuntustudio 14.04.

My Asus Q551 notebook with a 840m locks or freezes soon after log-in.  The Q551 has Ubuntu 14.04 (Lightdm/unity) with Ubuntustudio features installed later.  I have tried Nvidia drivers from Ubuntu, Xorg-Edgers and Nvidia propriatary repositories, all freezing.  The on-board Intel seems to work fine. But Lightworks software requires Nvidia features.  I have purged and reinstalled Nvidia drivers to no avail. (331 to present)  I should be using 340.xx.
No black screen as some have reported.

Many suggestions out there, but they haven't worked so far.  My question-- does anyone here have a good work around for this issue?

Comment: If you come to a dead end troubleshooting your nvidia card in Ubuntu (as I did), I suggest that you try LinuxMint, it's a distribution that makes an extra effort to support nvidia cards out of the box, and it fixed the problem in my ASUS laptop.